# Mobile development with JavaScript - too many options, what to choose?

Tags: android, javascript, software-development, ios, mobile

I want to develop an app using JavaScript to be supported in Android and iOS.

I only know JavaScript, so I don't have any experience with mobile app development.

Is there any tool that I can use to develop my application to produce native apps for Android and iOS?

Comment: Do you want free tools? If not what is your budget? What kind of website do you want to build? How many developers? Is maintainance important?

Comment: Hi Nicolas, thanks for your answer. The most important thing for me, is not  to feel outside of the frameworks am already using which is something like JS, and so on. What are the options available? Which one is "easier" to get into?

Comment: Please order the following from most important to less important to you: running speed, maintainability, easiness for people who know only JavaScript, cost, size of the APK, popularity/community, robustness, availability of paid support.

Comment: running speed, easiness for JS dev, robustness, cost

Comment: On which platform do you want to use this tool?

Answer (score 1):

I know  that there is React Native, built by Facebook (http://www.reactnative.com/). It's been out for a few years now, and I believe Facebook use it to build their apps in iOS and Android.

I'd be careful when using a cross platform mobile development solution e.g. Cordova, they tend to run slower than native code. It does depend on whether you need the native performance or not, and whether you're using it to do much intensive computing or not.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the preferred language for Android is Java, although you can use others. For iOs, it was objective C, until they invented Swift.

For browser-based work, I would strongly recommend AngulrJs over plain old JS.

But, my answer is **don't** develop native apps.

Leverage your existing skills. Look into [Cordova](https://cordova.apache.org/) from the Apache foundation. It is a free framework that let's you code HTML, CSS & JS - skills that you already have.

This will, of course, be cross-platform, which is a good thing.

The major point of Cordova is that it uses JS libraries to let you do what browsers normally can't. With it you can access a device's camera, GPS, microphone, address book, etc, etc.

Visit their web site & I am sure that you will be convinced (don't forget to look into AngularJS too).

Comment: Is it fast though? I've heard it's not fast and people are telling me to use Telerik or Ionic for development, am not sure where to go from here.

Comment: @BrittanyRutherford it depends on what you'll be doing with it...

Comment: I would imagine that it is not pure JS at the core. I woulld expect the libraries that access the hardware to be compiled native code. Of course, you ought to check that. But ist is certainly in very wide used, with the backing of Apache, so I would expect it to be acceptable.